# Screenshot app which allows getting only a part of a window when you can't use prtScr button

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot. The default screenshot app (16.04) works fine,
but I need to open gimp to cut the image. I just want a part of the window.

It would be great if there is a simple screenshot app which loads fast and which allows me to cut the image directly, without staring gimp.

Note: <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> button doesn't work on my keyboard

Comment: Do you want to take screenshot of section of your screen? without manually cropping it afterwords

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh yes, I want a part of a web page which I see in firefox.

Comment: try doing `Shift` + `PrtScn` (print screen), you'd be able to select the area on screen

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh the PrtScn key does not work on my keyboard.

Comment: then how do you generally take screenshot?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html

Comment: @guettli Which keyboard do you use? It's surprising to see that there isn't any prntScn button!

Comment: @Anwar I use it for a different purpose :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

It's more than a screenshot tool.

> You can take a screenshot of a specific area, window, your whole screen, or even of a website – apply different effects to it, draw on it to highlight points, and then upload to an image hosting site, all within one window.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Works fine. I upvote this question. I will wait some days until I give the final "best answer".